# pandas: merge conditional on time range

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'd like to merge one data frame with another, where the merge is conditional on the date/time falling in a particular range.

For example, let's say I have the following two data frames.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# Create main data frame.
data = pd.DataFrame()
time_seq1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('1/1/2016', periods=3, freq='H'))
time_seq2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('1/2/2016', periods=3, freq='H'))
data = data.append(time_seq1, ignore_index=True)
data = data.append(time_seq1, ignore_index=True)
data = data.append(time_seq1, ignore_index=True)
data = data.append(time_seq2, ignore_index=True)
data['myID'] = ['001','001','001','002','002','002','003','003','003','004','004','004']
data.columns = ['Timestamp', 'myID']

# Create second data frame.
data2 = pd.DataFrame()
data2['time'] = [pd.to_datetime('1/1/2016 12:06 AM'), pd.to_datetime('1/1/2016 1:34 AM'), pd.to_datetime('1/2/2016 12:25 AM')]
data2['myID'] = ['002', '003', '004']
data2['specialID'] = ['foo_0', 'foo_1', 'foo_2']

# Show data frames.
data
             Timestamp myID
0  2016-01-01 00:00:00  001
1  2016-01-01 01:00:00  001
2  2016-01-01 02:00:00  001
3  2016-01-01 00:00:00  002
4  2016-01-01 01:00:00  002
5  2016-01-01 02:00:00  002
6  2016-01-01 00:00:00  003
7  2016-01-01 01:00:00  003
8  2016-01-01 02:00:00  003
9  2016-01-02 00:00:00  004
10 2016-01-02 01:00:00  004
11 2016-01-02 02:00:00  004

data2
                 time myID specialID
0 2016-01-01 00:06:00  002     foo_0
1 2016-01-01 01:34:00  003     foo_1
2 2016-01-02 00:25:00  004     foo_2
```

I would like to construct the following output.

```
# Desired output.
             Timestamp myID special_ID
0  2016-01-01 00:00:00  001        NaN
1  2016-01-01 01:00:00  001        NaN
2  2016-01-01 02:00:00  001        NaN
3  2016-01-01 00:00:00  002        NaN
4  2016-01-01 01:00:00  002      foo_0
5  2016-01-01 02:00:00  002        NaN
6  2016-01-01 00:00:00  003        NaN
7  2016-01-01 01:00:00  003        NaN
8  2016-01-01 02:00:00  003      foo_1
9  2016-01-02 00:00:00  004        NaN
10 2016-01-02 01:00:00  004      foo_2
11 2016-01-02 02:00:00  004        NaN
```

In particular, I want to merge `special_ID` into `data` such that `Timestamp` is the first time occurring after the value of `time`. For example, `foo_0` would be in the row corresponding to `2016-01-01 01:00:00` with `myID = 002` since that is the next time in `data` immediately following `2016-01-01 00:06:00` (the `time` of `special_ID = foo_0`) among the rows containing `myID = 002`.

Note, `Timestamp` is not the index of `data` and `time` is not the index of `data2`. Most other related posts seem to rely on using the datetime object as the index of the data frame.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html), which is new in Pandas 0.19, to do most of the work.  Then, combine `loc` and `duplicated` to remove secondary matches:

```
# Data needs to be sorted for merge_asof.
data = data.sort_values(by='Timestamp')

# Perform the merge_asof.
df = pd.merge_asof(data, data2, left_on='Timestamp', right_on='time', by='myID').drop('time', axis=1)

# Make the additional matches null.
df.loc[df['specialID'].duplicated(), 'specialID'] = np.nan

# Get the original ordering.
df = df.set_index(data.index).sort_index()
```

The resulting output:

```
             Timestamp myID specialID
0  2016-01-01 00:00:00  001       NaN
1  2016-01-01 01:00:00  001       NaN
2  2016-01-01 02:00:00  001       NaN
3  2016-01-01 00:00:00  002       NaN
4  2016-01-01 01:00:00  002     foo_0
5  2016-01-01 02:00:00  002       NaN
6  2016-01-01 00:00:00  003       NaN
7  2016-01-01 01:00:00  003       NaN
8  2016-01-01 02:00:00  003     foo_1
9  2016-01-02 00:00:00  004       NaN
10 2016-01-02 01:00:00  004     foo_2
11 2016-01-02 02:00:00  004       NaN
```

Comment: perfect!  I was just working on this, now I don't have to.  :-)

Comment: You have some kind of a bug, you changed the Timestamp of data

Comment: @Oren: No, my output is just sorted slightly differently.

Comment: @root thanks! Could you edit your response to preserve the original order? Then I'll mark this as solved.

Comment: @Adam: Updated to maintain the original ordering.  The method I used assumes that your original index is just the default ordered `Int64Index`, as it is in the example data.

Comment: perfect solution！

Answer (score 0):

Not very beautiful, but i think it works.

```
data['specialID'] = None
foolist = list(data2['myID'])
for i in data.index:
    if data.myID[i] in foolist:
        if data.Timestamp[i]> list(data2[data2['myID'] == data.myID[i]].time)[0]:
            data['specialID'][i] = list(data2[data2['myID'] == data.myID[i]].specialID)[0]
            foolist.remove(list(data2[data2['myID'] == data.myID[i]].myID)[0])

In [95]: data
Out[95]:
             Timestamp myID specialID
0  2016-01-01 00:00:00  001      None
1  2016-01-01 01:00:00  001      None
2  2016-01-01 02:00:00  001      None
3  2016-01-01 00:00:00  002      None
4  2016-01-01 01:00:00  002     foo_0
5  2016-01-01 02:00:00  002      None
6  2016-01-01 00:00:00  003      None
7  2016-01-01 01:00:00  003      None
8  2016-01-01 02:00:00  003     foo_1
9  2016-01-02 00:00:00  004      None
10 2016-01-02 01:00:00  004     foo_2
11 2016-01-02 02:00:00  004      None
```